# R Shiny two rows by two columns

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to place four plots in a two rows by two columns layout. The code below returns two rows by one column. How can the second column be added?

Any help is appreciated.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
                fluidRow(
                        column(6,
                               plotOutput(outputId = "hist1")
                        ),
                        column(6,
                                plotOutput(outputId = "hist2")
                        )
                )
)

    server <- function(input,output){
            output$hist1 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(rnorm(100,50,5))
            })
            output$hist2 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(rnorm(100,75,5))
            })
            output$hist3 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(rnorm(100,100,5))
            })
            output$hist4 <- renderPlot({
                    hist(rnorm(100,125,5))
            })
    }

    runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Change `shinyUI(fluidRow(...))` to `shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(...)))`

Comment: Awesome, that's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from brittenb in comments : `fluidPage()` needs to be added.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
                fluidRow(
                        column(6,
                                plotOutput(outputId = "hist1")
                        ),
                        column(6,
                               plotOutput(outputId = "hist2")
                        )
                ),
                fluidRow(
                        column(6,
                               plotOutput(outputId = "hist3")
                        ),
                        column(6,
                               plotOutput(outputId = "hist4")
                        )
                )
        )
)

server <- function(input,output){
        output$hist1 <- renderPlot({
                hist(rnorm(100,50,5))
        })
        output$hist2 <- renderPlot({
                hist(rnorm(100,75,5))
        })
        output$hist3 <- renderPlot({
                hist(rnorm(100,100,5))
        })
        output$hist4 <- renderPlot({
                hist(rnorm(100,125,5))
        })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```